# Window.open not working in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

My application is in asp.net in which my i am trying to open new tab with some data. For this i have written below line of code which is not working in internet explorer 11.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('JobTickets.aspx','_newtab');", true);
```

same line of code is working on IE 10,9,8 etc. as well as on Firefox and chrome.
Also confirm box is also not working on IE 11.

Thanks,

Comment: When you say it's not working do you get an error message? Does anything happen? Have you checked popup blocker>?

Comment: @JoshBerke= Yes, i check error but there is no js error in console.Also  no popup blocker enabled, even i tried disabling  protected mode but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncehck protected mode.
2. Turn off IE popup blocket. (Not sure if you are referring to IE's or 3rd party plugins.
3. Try with Compatibility mode. Might give you more to debug on.

Comment: options you suggest are already tried but still having problem.